# Getting the following error log in android application. Please help me

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

```
06-25 07:04:19.985: W/System.err(1398): org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
06-25 07:04:20.005: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
06-25 07:04:20.005: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
06-25 07:04:20.017: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
06-25 07:04:20.017: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
06-25 07:04:20.017: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
06-25 07:04:20.025: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
06-25 07:04:20.025: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
06-25 07:04:20.025: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
06-25 07:04:20.035: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-25 07:04:20.035: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-25 07:04:20.045: W/System.err(1398):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-25 07:04:20.045: W/System.err(1398):     at com.example.androidhive.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:47)
06-25 07:04:20.055: W/System.err(1398):     at com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:38)
06-25 07:04:20.055: W/System.err(1398):     at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:61)
06-25 07:04:20.055: W/System.err(1398):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-25 07:04:20.065: W/System.err(1398):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-25 07:04:20.075: W/System.err(1398):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-25 07:04:20.095: W/System.err(1398):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-25 07:04:20.095: W/System.err(1398):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-25 07:04:20.095: W/System.err(1398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-25 07:04:20.115: W/System.err(1398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 07:04:20.115: W/System.err(1398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-25 07:04:20.125: W/System.err(1398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-25 07:04:20.125: W/System.err(1398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-25 07:04:20.125: W/System.err(1398):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 07:04:20.125: E/Buffer Error(1398): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
06-25 07:04:20.135: E/JSON Parser(1398): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
06-25 07:04:20.145: D/AndroidRuntime(1398): Shutting down VM
06-25 07:04:20.145: W/dalvikvm(1398): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at com.example.androidhive.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:65)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-25 07:04:20.185: E/AndroidRuntime(1398):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### LoginActivity.java

```
   

    package com.example.androidhive;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler;
    import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;

    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        Button btnLogin;
        Button btnLinkToRegister;
        EditText inputEmail;
        EditText inputPassword;
        TextView loginErrorMsg;

        // JSON Response node names
        private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
        private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
        private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
        private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
        private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);

            // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
            loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

            // Login button Click Event
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
                    UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                    Log.d("Button", "Login");
                    JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                    // check for login response
                    try {
                        if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                            loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                            String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                            if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                                // user successfully logged in
                                // Store user details in SQLite Database
                                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                                JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                                // Clear all previous data in database
                                userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                                db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                                // Launch Dashboard Screen
                                Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                                // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(dashboard);

                                // Close Login Screen
                                finish();
                            }else{
                                // Error in login
                                loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            // Link to Register Screen
            btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your LoginActivity code.

Comment: and also mention that which is line number 65 in LoginActivity.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at line 65 in your LoginActivity. Check it first

Comment: @Raghunandan Please check my LoginActivity Code...

Comment: @BalajiRethinam i did can you tell what's line 65?

Comment: @Raghunandan DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
       JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

Comment: use ActivityContext `LoginActivity.this` and check if json_user is null or not.

Comment: so what was the actual error that caused using `getApplicationContext()`?

Answer (score 1):

As several people have pointed out, in your LoginActivity on line 65 you're attempting to access a null object; which is throwing an exception.  You should look at what you're doing on that line and see if there are any object instances that you received from another API that could potentially return null.